# what can I do to clean up my question?

Tags: discussion

[What piece am I missing to turn this idea into a programming language?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/what-piece-am-i-missing-to-turn-this-idea-into-a-programming-language)

Reading over it now, I can't help but completely agree with the last comment that it isn't clear what I'm asking. And I admit it. I don't know what I'm looking for. But I *have* done this "research".

I suppose in its current form it does devolve to "what other fun stuff should I look at". But I'm not sure what to do about it. *edit:* I have made a few revisions to incorporate new ideas.

Would it be enough to add a paragraph about "The goal is to make a Turing-Complete esoteric programming language with interesting properties (wrt. codegolf-ability, Kolmogorov-complexity, relation to other models (Turing Machine, Minsky Register Machine, Cellular Automata), etc)" ?

Replace the ASCII-art with better-looking tree diagrams?

Comment: Oh, not even a comment so far. I have no idea, really; I have to admit that I have not read the question carefully. The title and pitch (e.g. first paragraph) promise tinkering, and when I scroll down and see that ASCII art (;)) I don't feel motivated digging into the matter. So maybe you can attract more people with a more focused question (pick one problem your language has) and pitch it better.

Comment: Well it is all speculative. I imagine most readers get halfway through the question and then wander away in a happy daydream.